# Implementing toString method and constructor in ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search, arraylist

I implement a adresbook and a adress class! I want to implement a method "searchForename" and "searchSurename" which search element which i added before with "insert". I looked at other implementations with ArrayList which search objects or elements,but mostly they are really confusing me because too much code w/o any Explanation.

THIRD EDIT WITH NEW QUESTIONS!:

Third try:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Adressbook {

    private ArrayList<Adress> adresses = null;

    public Adressbook(){
        adresses = new ArrayList<Adress>();
    }

    public void insert(Adress adress){
        adresses.add(new Adress("Marvin","Wildman","Blastreet",9,12345,"Blatown"));
        adresses.add(new Adress("Anne","Wildman","Woodstreet",10,6789,"Exampletown"));
        adresses.add(new Adress("William","Wildman","Eaglestreet",11,73975,"Blubvalley"));
    }


    public void searchSurename(String surename){
        for(Adress s: adresses){
            if("Green".equals(surename)){
            System.out.println(s);
            }
        }

    }

    public void searchForename(String forename){
        for(Adress s: adresses){
            if("Anne".equals(forename)){
            System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return null;

    }

}
```

I have few questions:

1.How does the toString method in Adressbook look like?

2.How does the toString at Adress class Look like ?

3.Does the Constructor looks correct in the Adress class?

4.Can i implement the searching method easier/more efficient than this? If it is not correct,how can i Change it?

Forgot my class Adress:

```
public class Adress {
    public static String forename;
    public static String surename;
    public static String street;
    public static int houseno;
    public static int code;
    public static String state;



    public Adress(String forename, String surename, String street, int houseno, int code,String state){
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surename = surename;
        this.street = street;
        this.houseno = houseno;
        this.code = code;
        this.state = state;
    }



    public String toString(){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Learn  [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this topic. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: On a side note address is spelt address. Typos in variables names are best avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is a `static` method and that's why you can't use the `this` in a static context as there is no object instance in a call of a static method.

```
public static String searchSurename // static method
```

You need to remove the `static` from your method declaration.

In case you can't do the above change, then you'll have to make your `ArrayList adresses` as `static`.

Also, as a side note, use the `equals()` for String value comparisons. `==` is for object refernce comparison.

```
if(this.adresses.get(i).getSurename().equals(surename)) {
```